# How to truncate element when outside of div

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout : http://jsfiddle.net/7C2R8/

The blue container is my  page.

I position my image with negative margins :

```
.image-wrapper {
    float:right;
    margin-top:-250px;
    margin-right:-100px;
}
```

The image is where I want it to be and the whole thing works the way I want it to on a big screen.

The problem comes when the viewport is smaller. For example, if the viewport is the size of the container (500px wide in my example) then a scroll bar appears on the x axis to see the image. This is what I don't want. I would like for my image to be truncated when not enough space is available. The container is the only thing that should scroll.

[image: Layout problem]

The image should be fully visible when the viewport is big enough.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by adding a wrapper around container that has

```
width:100%;
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Now this might not work in every situation, but in this case, the design is responsive and there should never be any scrolling on the x-axis so it works fine.

Working solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/Z3m7m/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to your `.container` class.

Update: you need to monitor the width when the page load and if resizes. Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7C2R8/6/).

```
$('document').ready(function () { 

    MonitorViewportResize();    
    DoImageOverflow();
});

function DoImageOverflow() {

    if ($(window).width() > 500) {
        $('.container').css('overflow','visible');
    } else {
        $('.container').css('overflow','hidden');
    }
}

function MonitorViewportResize() {

    $(window).resize(function() {
        DoImageOverflow();
    });
}
```

Basically, we set the `overflow` attribute based on the width of the window. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: That will truncate the image all the time, even when the viewport is big enough. As I said in the question, the image should be fully visible when the viewport is big enough. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @HugoMigneron: see update; I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that will work with a little bit of work (for when the window is 505px wide for example) but it's fine. I was hoping for a CSS way to do this but it might not be possible. Thanks for your help in any case.

Comment: Ok, glad to help. There's no way to do this in CSS, only with javascript.

Comment: Just FYI, I managed to get it working with CSS only. See my answer and here : http://jsfiddle.net/Z3m7m/1/

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for overflow:hidden;

```
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: No, that will truncate the image all the time, even when the viewport is big enough. As I said in the question, the image should be fully visible when the viewport is big enough.

Comment: Then you may not put the image inside of the container. You can also disable the scrollbars of the page itself.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Even if I take the image out of the container, I still have the same problem. (window scrolling when viewport is too small)

Comment: body {
        overflow:hidden;
    }

Comment: This is what I end up with when I do that which is not an acceptable result either : http://jsfiddle.net/DBFdC/